# Django: how to connect customizable url to GET method

Tags: python, html, django, rest, web

I want to implement a search method that takes as filters properties selected by user from front-end side. The URL I want to create would be something like:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_data),
    path(r'^find/<property>/<filter>/<value>', views.filter_view)
]
```

Where

`<property>` is the value (1-9) selected from:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper" style="padding-left: 0px">
                             <select class="dropdown" id="select-properties-dropdown">
                                 <option class="property" value="0">Select property</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="1">GID</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="2">Type</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="3">Province</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="4">Street</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="5">House number</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="6">Postcode</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="7">City</option>
                                 <option class="property" value="8">Municipality</option>
                             </select>
</div>
```

`<filter>` is the value from:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper" >
                     <select class="dropdown">
                         <option class="property" value="0">Contains</option>
                         <option class="property" value="1">Equal to</option>
                         <option class="property" value="2">Ends with</option>
                         <option class="property" value="3">Starts with</option>
                     </select>

</div>
```

and `<value>` is the taken from the searchbar:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
                <form action="find" method="GET">
                     <input class="input searchbar" type="text"
                            aria-autocomplete="list"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            id="searchBar"
                            style="height: 28.5px"
                     >
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>


</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply get them from the querystring?..

Answer (score 0):

Use django `forms`. They have `widget`s that emulate `<select>`. You can later use the form in django CBVs like `FormView` and add your own functionality by simply overriding the `form_valid()` method.

```
from django import forms

PROPERTY_CHOICES = [    
    ('1', 'GID'),
    ('2', 'Type'),
    ('3', 'Province'),
    #...
    ]
FILTER_CHOICES = [
    ('0', 'contains'),
    ('1', 'Equal'),
    ('2', 'Ends'),
    ('3', 'Starts'),
    #...
]

class PropertyForm(forms.Form):
    property = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=PROPERTY_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'property'}))
    filter = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FILTER_CHOICES) # uses the select widget
    value = forms.CharField()
```